# How to make the audio music work in ruby and shoes?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am using ruby language and shoes for the Gui.

I put the code below in the shoes, but all of the Gui shoes disappear and it gives me a blank screen. I downloaded the kahoot music and when I delete the code below, all the shoes code work.

```
song = Music.new('KahootLobbyMusic.mp3')
song.play
```

Is there any advice for this?

Comment: I think I read something telling that producing sound in Shoes can be achieved only through VLC. I'm starting with Shoes 3.3.7